# what is most efficient way to search in list of dicts DART

Tags: flutter, dart

what is most efficient way to search in list of dicts in dart

eg. I want to find a guy with a param == 2

```
List objects = [
    {"a": 1, "b": "John", "c": "Doe"},
    {"a": 2, "b": "Jane", "c": "Doe"},
    {"a": 3, "b": "Mary", "c": "Smith"},
   ];

  String name = "none";

  for (var object in objects) {
    if (object["a"] == 2) {
      name = object["b"];
      break;
    }
  }

  print(name); // Jane
```

Are there any more efficient ways?

Comment: "Are there any more efficient ways?" if you search only *once* on that data, then no. If you search multiple times, you can be more efficient by bringing your data in a more efficient format. But that depends on how many times you search and what the cost-benefit of amout of searches to time to optimize the data is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `where` function from dart Lists.

For example

```
List objects = [
    {"a": 1, "b": "John", "c": "Doe"},
    {"a": 2, "b": "Jane", "c": "Doe"},
    {"a": 3, "b": "Mary", "c": "Smith"},
   ];

var filtered = objects.where((item) => item["a"] == 2).toList();

print(filtered); //[{a: 2, b: Jane, c: Doe}]
```

`filtered` will contain a list with all the items that satisfies `item["a"] == 2`.

Short and concise, without needing to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> objects = [
  {"a": 1, "b": "John", "c": "Doe"},
  {"a": 2, "b": "Jane", "c": "Doe"},
  {"a": 3, "b": "Mary", "c": "Smith"},
];

int searchParam = 2;
String name = objects
    .firstWhere((object) => object["a"] == searchParam, orElse: () => null)
    ?.["b"] ?? "none";

print(name); // Jane
```